# Exclusive access to method/field

Tags: java

In my application I have a class which has a variable which gets updated everytime a new event comes in:

```
class Logger{

  private String mVariable ="";

  public void onEvent(Event e) {
    //update mVariable here
  }

  public void log() {
     //write mVariable to file
  }
}
```

Now, I have another class which wants to trigger the Logger class to write the current value to a file.

```
class Trigger{

   //this is another event, not the event for which Logger is waiting for
   public void onEvent(Event e) {
      mLogger.log();
   }
}
```

How can I ensure that the `Trigger` class has exclusive access to the value of `mVariable` whenever it wants? i.e. When the `Trigger` class calls the `log` method the value of `mVariable` should not be overridden by the `Logger` class of course.

Comment: you mean mLogger.log(); will trigger onEvent(Event e) ?

Comment: no, both, the `onEvent` method of `Logger` and the `onEvent` method of `Trigger` are completely unrelated. They are called from an eventbus.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: making the methods synchronized just makes sure that they are not executed at the same time. How dan I ensure that the Trigger class doesn't have to wait, but can call the log() method whenever it wants?

Comment: So how exactly do you want this to behave if Logger is in the middle of writing and trigger needs access without waiting? You don't have to make an entire method synchronized. Do explicit locking only around the relevant bits that actually write to the variable. But if one thing already got access, there's no way to magically roll-back everything it did in order to give priority to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Make both methods `synchronized` then calling lock() will lock access to onEvent()